# Is there any method by which I can restrict other user not to view my container in Azure data lake gen 2

Tags: azure, security, containers, azure-data-lake-gen2

Problem Statement- There are two different teams working on two different project for same client. Both team have access to azure resource group on which azure data lake storage has been created. Now Client want us to use same data lake storage for both project but they also want that team working on a specific containers should not have access to other containers which other team will use and vice-versa.

> Example--
>
> > Azure data lake storage -both team have access to this
> > ->container1--only team 1 should have access to this
> > ->container2--only team 2 should have access to this

Can anyone please suggest that how can we achieve this.

Thanks In advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the access to containers, directories and blobs by using Access control lists (ACLs) feature in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

You can associate a [security principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#security-principal) with an access level for files and directories. Each association is captured as an entry in an access control list (ACL). Each file and directory in your storage account has an access control list. When a security principal attempts an operation on a file or directory, An ACL check determines whether that security principal (user, group, service principal, or managed identity) has the correct permission level to perform the operation.

To manage the ACL on the container, follow the below steps:

1. Go to the container in the storage account.

[image]

2. Navigate to any container, directory, or blob. Right-click the object, and then select Manage ACL.

[image]

The Access permissions tab of the Manage ACL page appears. Use the controls in this tab to manage access to the object.

[image]

3. To add a security principal to the ACL, select the Add principal button.

Find the security principal by using the search box, and then click the Select button.

[image]

**You should create a security group in Azure AD for each of your team, and then maintain permissions on the group rather than for individual users.**

Refer: [Access control lists (ACLs) in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control)

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh!! We tried it but it don't seem to work as team member from team 1 and team 2 has access to the resource group and from there ,hierarchy access will come, That means whatever has been created in the resource group, everyone will have access to those.

Comment: Have you tried through Azure AD security group? It's fine if both team has access to the resource group. The ACL allows RBAC which allows only the members who has access to the resources and deny the unauthorized(no access) access even in the same resource group.

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh. You are right ,we can use the above method only when the user don't have contributor role assign on the resources group itself. Having contributor role on the RG ,means you have access to everything inside that RG. We have managed to do it by first removing the contributor role and then creating custom role for every user and giving access to the required service (ADF,Databricks,Datalake ) using RBAC and ACL.

Comment: Glad it worked. If my answer helps you to resolve your problem I request you to please upvote and accept the answer to help other community members.